# Multiple automatic replies on a single day with Office 365 Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365

I wish to be able to have multiple "out of office" like automatic replies on my email without having to manually turn it on or off all the time.

For example I would like to setup a schedule say Monday - Friday where I am sending automatic replies between 9-12 and 1-4.  Is this possible in Microsoft  Office 365 Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously there was **Out of Office Assistant** with Outlook but with **Office 365** Microsoft made the whole process quite easier.

You can create multiple templates and set rules accordingly.

Here are the steps to get it done:

1. Create a message template.
2. Click Home > New Email.
3. Type your message
4. In the message window, click File > Save As --
5. Make sure in the **Save As dialog box, in the Save as type list, choose Outlook Template**
6. Give a name to your template via File name box.
7. Now, create a rule to automatically reply to new email messages.

**Rules Part:**

1. Click Home > Rules > Manage Rules & Alerts.
2. In the Rules and Alerts dialog box, click New Rule.
3. Under Start from a blank rule, click Apply rules on messages I receive, and then click Next.

Under Which condition(s) do you want to check?, check any criteria that you want, and then click Next. Typically, you don’t need to check any items.

Under What do you want to do with the message?, check reply using a specific template.

Under Step 2: Edit the rule description (click an underlined value), click a specific template.

In the Select a Reply Template dialog box, in the Look In box, click User Templates in File System.

Select the template that you created in the previous section or one that you have created or downloaded, and then click Open.

Click Next.

Check any exceptions to the auto-reply rule. It’s common not to add any exceptions.

Click Next.

Under Step 1: Specify a name for this rule, type a name for the auto-reply rule, and then click Finish.

**Note -** For the Rules Wizard to send a reply automatically, Outlook must be running and configured to check periodically for new messages.

Comment: Ah, so the catch here was outlook had to be running.  I wonder if there is a way to get this type of functionality without it running?

Comment: @dreza I am following up with my fellas at Redmond but I think there is no other way to do it as connection is required to send mails

Comment: Anytime @dreza :)
Checked back on the progress with Outlook Program Manager. No development underway on adding this feature.